# purpose of declaring foreign keys in mysql MyISAM engine

Tags: mysql

I just came to know that mysql `MyISAM` engine doesn't support foreign keys.But i have seen several example of declaring `foreign` keys like below :

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

As foreign keys are not supported we would not get the benefits like  `on update` and `on delete` in MyISAM engine.My question is then why we are declaring a field as foreign key in MyISAM engine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point of declaring foreign keys with the myisam table type, since this functionality does not exist there. Mysql can **parse** the foreign key syntax for the myisam table type (meaning no error message will be raised if it encounters an fk definition), making migration from other database products or table engines easier because you do not have to edit the `create table` statements to remove them.