# Mysql creates index instead of foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I am trying to create an foreign key constraint between two tables but after I execute the alter command mysql creates index instead of foreign key.

I am using hibernate, so initially i thought this to be a problem of hibernate but when i execute the query directly on mysql behavior is same.

> alter table person add constraint FK9ircw28d19mdg5pu8yfg1qs8p foreign key (Address_Id) references Address (Address_Id)

After running this command, i get following in mysql database

[image]

As you can see constraint is added in indexes rather than as Foreign key.

Hibernate executes following queries while creating tables:

> Hibernate: drop table if exists Address
>
> Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
>
> Hibernate: drop table if exists person
>
> Hibernate: create table Address (Address_Id bigint not null, addressLine1 varchar(255), addressLine2 varchar(255), city varchar(255) not null, country varchar(255) not null, state varchar(255) not null, primary key (Address_Id)) engine=MyISAM
>
> Hibernate: create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) engine=MyISAM
>
> Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
>
> Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
>
> Hibernate: create table person (Person_Id bigint not null, dob date not null, name varchar(255) not null, Address_Id bigint, primary key (Person_Id)) engine=MyISAM
>
> Hibernate: alter table person add constraint FK9ircw28d19mdg5pu8yfg1qs8p foreign key (Address_Id) references Address (Address_Id)

Comment: What exactly am I looking at? Post the show create table output please.

Comment: MyISAM [does not support foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102244/6248528). Use InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks It solved problem. You can put it as answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Solarflare. It solved my problem. Issue was MyISAM engine does not support foreign keys. Once I changed the engine type to InnoDB, things worked as expected.